# Workflow movement from one stage to another stage in SharePoint using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a workflow in SharePoint designer and added few stages and depending on the conditions it moves to the another stage. Now the problem which is am facing is that its not moving to the another stage even the condition is met.
Please me help to resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Anita

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your stages(steps) and the conditions themselves, I am working on the assumption that your condition does not quite match the input  the workflow is expecting. An example would be the use of a Boolean field in SharePoint. While a list or library will have Yes/No as your chosen responses. In Designer, using the boolean field may result True/False or even lowercase version. I experienced a similar issue when I developed an InfoPath form that required a lowercase 'true' response to be deliberately spelled out in the Designer Workflow as using Uppercase 'True' did not trigger my workflow. Please review your conditions. That is all I can recommend at this time.